# Setting textbox to readonly not working in Javascript

Tags: javascript, textbox, readonly

I have tried the following codes to set a textbox property to readonly but none of them is working. Can anyone tell me how to do it?

```
document.getElementById("phone_numbers").disabled=true;
document.getElementById("phone_numbers").readonly=true;
document.getElementById("phone_numbers").readOnly=true;
document.getElementById("phone_numbers").readOnly=readOnly;
document.getElementById("phone_numbers").readOnly=readonly;
document.getElementById("phone_numbers").readonly=readonly;
document.getElementById("phone_numbers").readonly=readOnly;
document.getElementById("phone_numbers").setAttribute('readonly', 'readonly');
document.getElementById("phone_numbers").setAttribute("readonly", "true");
```

**EDIT**
While I was editing my question to write more detail I realized what the problem was. I made a silly mistake. This was my original HTML code.

```
<input name="phone_numbers">
```

And I changed it to

```
<input id="phone_numbers">
```

And it worked!

By the way following are the functions that are actually working.

```
document.getElementById("phone_numbers").disabled=true;
document.getElementById("phone_numbers").readOnly=true;
document.getElementById("phone_numbers").setAttribute('readonly', 'readonly');
document.getElementById("phone_numbers").setAttribute("readonly", "true");
```

Comment: Some of those work fine, can you post your html so we can see how the id is set

Comment: Works good http://jsfiddle.net/M4n6A/ - your problem is somewhere else maybe.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about syntax errors

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your third line worked for me: **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rLVNX/)**

**HTML**

```
<input id="phone_numbers" type="textbox"></input>
```

**Javascript**

```
document.getElementById("phone_numbers").readOnly=true;
```

Comment: Ah the capital O

Answer (score 0):

If the `textbox` is server side, then use `document.getElementById("<%= phone_numbers.ClientId %>")` to access it.